# To bind clear to ^l in Bash

Tags: bash, binding

I would like to have `Ctrl-l` for `clear` in my  Bash.

**How can you bind `Ctrl-l` to `clear` in Bash?**

Comment: What's wrong with Ctrl+K, or do you have little hands and can't reach K (right next to L on Qwerty keyboards)?! :-P

Comment: Ctrl+K does not work. I use Dvorak. --- I have had the idea that Ctrl-l is the default `clear` in Bash and Zsh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
C-L: backward-kill-line
```

(assuming by "clear" you mean "clear current input line"; if you mean "clear screen" then put `clear-screen` instead of `backward-kill-line`).

Comment: I mean the latter one. -- I put `C-L clear-screen` to ~/.inputrc unsuccessfully. This suggests me that ~/.inputrc is not sourced by Bash. However, Bash does not like if I source the file at .bashrc. -- Where should I put the code?

Comment: `.inputrc` isn't *sourced* by bash, exactly; it doesn't contain `bash` commands, it contains readline library configuration directives.  The environment variable INPUTRC can be used to override the default location of `~/.inputrc`; conceivably that may be set.  And you do need to start a new `bash` in order for it to take effect; it won't affect existing sessions.

Comment: @Dennis: It did that for me half a year ago. But after using Zsh for that period, it does not work for some reason. --- This suggests me that there must be some other file than .inputrc which needs to be changed to get `clear` work.

Comment: Well, that isn't the case for me.  `C-L: clear-screen` in `~/.inputrc` works fine on my logins.  I don't know what's going on with yours.

Comment: `C-L: clear-screen` doesn't work for me either. But someone somewhere suggested this that worked: `"\C-l":'clear\n'`

Answer (score 7):

in a particular case where the `clear-screen` didn't work for me either, I found out that putting in `~/.bashrc` the line: `bind -x $'"\C-l":clear;'` was better than `"\C-l":'clear\n'` in `~/.inputrc` because it cleared the screen **and** left the currently typed command in place; for example (`^L` show where I hit the combo):

With `"\C-l": clear-screen` in `~/.inputrc`:

```sh
user@darkstar:~$ date^L
user@darkstar:~$ date
user@darkstar:~$ ^L
user@darkstar:~$
```

With `"\C-l":'clear\n'` in `~/.inputrc`:

```sh
user@darkstar:~$ date^L
-bash: dateclear: command not found
user@darkstar:~$ ^L
# screen effectively redrawn
```

With `bind -x $'"\C-l":clear;'` in `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
user@darkstar:~$ date^L
# screen redrawn and the top line is now:
user@darkstar:~$ date
```

And for now I have not been able to get the same result as `bind -x` using only the inputrc file...

## Edit

I found that in some cases where `clear-screen` wasn't working for me were caused by my attempts to get more colors in the CLI.
For example I had the issue with `TERM=xterm-256color` (or `screen-256color`, etc.) and removing the `-256color` part solved the problem.

I have not yet found a way to get a 256 colors term working along <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (in xterm, urxvt, etc).

Comment: What you mean by this *And for now I have not been able to get the same result as bind -x using only the inputrc file...*. Do you have still `bind -x $'"\C-l":clear;'` in `$HOME/.bashrc`? Do you mean in .bashrc only instead as your other text suggests?

Comment: @Masi < Yes I still `bind -x` from`.bashrc`, and only from it, because I have not found a way to achieve the same results using `.inputrc` only. My answer was an attempt to "show" the different solutions and their differents results in my environment. Do not hesitate to reword my text if you think it is not well formulated or tell me if you think screenshots would add a value.

Comment: Slackware and derivative distros (at least v14.1) don't support any "-256color" terminal (at least with bash). Even though the terminfo included in Slackware has support for *-256color, bash is compiled with termcap. I guess you can create a custom termcap entry for that or recompile bash. I'm having this problem when connecting from Ubuntu 20.04 to Slackware 14.1 with ssh to a bash (the TERM is set to xterm-256color).